# Bitmap turns to black when saving to storage

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

Every time I try to save an image it turns to black I don't know what's wrong with it.

Here is my relevant code please take a look.

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String fname = "image.png";

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File mypath = new File(directory, fname);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `e.printStackTrace();`  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No I'm not getting any exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to the transparency of images，You try to change the format of the picture or change the bitmap's alpha value. 
You can refer to this:[black bitmap](http://blog.csdn.net/linhui9010/article/details/18765811)

Comment: The link you gave me contains some error and I'm not able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it myself.

It seems that if you use your internal storage and set `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` when I try to open it with my file explorer it display black screen even if the you have super user access.

So what I did is access the file via the app with this line of code.

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
try {
    File f = new File(directory, "image.png");
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    image.setImageBitmap(b);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```